# Limiting list view for profiles

Tags: customer-community, list-view

Basically i need list views for customer community users alone. But we have an option of views only enabled for both "customer and portal users". So i need to know if list views can be restricted for profiles alone, so that customer community users alone can have a view of it ? is it possible ? i am new to salesforce, Please help me with it. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List Views cannot be restricted by profiles only Groups and Roles, if you are using Customer Community licences then those users will not have an associated role so you will be limited to using Groups. You can set a List View for Customer Portal roles only thereby preventing that list view from being used by the internal users - see image.

[image]

Customer Community Plus licences do have roles, but there is usually one or more of these for each customer company, e.g. account ACME would normally have ACME Customer Executive, ACME Customer Manager, ACME Customer User. The access can be granted by role or role and subordinates like an internal role, but you would need to add this for each new customer account added that had community users.